# How to apply css and js with nodejs express?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

Following is my folder tree.

```
lifecoding
|login2
 |index.html
 |css
  style.css
 |js
  index.js
```

I am using express and all the modules needed are completely installed.
I set the static path, as follows, but it doesn't work and keep saying the file 'index.html' is not located.

The reason I am using static path in order to apply css and js file well.
Give me some tips, thanks.

```
app.get('/auth/login', function(req, res){
  res.send(output);*/
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/login2')));
  res.sendFile('/index.html');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First: move this:

> ```
> app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/login2')));
> ```

You setup to bind your middleware **once**, when the application loads.

Don't do it every time the login page is requested.

---

> it doesn't work and keep saying the file 'index.html' is not located.

Second: Write the correct path to the index file.

> ```
> /index.html
> ```

`sendFile` deals with file paths, not URLs. It isn't in the root of your computers file system.

```
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/login2/index.html'))
```

Comment: I did exactly same as you recommend, but the css and js file are not applied. I don't get it....